# Can a phrase be passed directly into sed?

Tags: bash, sed

If I want to run a search/replace pattern on the first argument to a bash function (`$1`), is it possible to pass it directly into `sed`, or do I have to execute `echo "$1" | sed ...`?

Comment: How else would you pass it to sed if not through stdin?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's literally the exact question that I'm asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` expects filenames as input. If it doesn't get any filenames, it reads from standard input. If you have text (such as your argument) that isn't in a file, you pipe it to `sed`.

Alternatively, you can use process substitution (bash feature), which allows text to appear as a file to programs that usually take file names/paths:

```
sed 's///g' <(echo "$1")
```

Or you can use either a here document, like so:

```
FOO=$(sed 's///g' <<EOF
$1
EOF
)
```

Or a here string (bash feature):

```
sed 's///g' <<< "$1"
```

Though using the pipe operator is the most simple and straightforward way to get your job done, in my opinion. Hope this helped expose you to the other possibilities.